# Designated initializer and initWithFrame

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've created a class with designated initializer defined that way:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
          aProperty:(float)value {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if(self){   
        ///....do something 
    }
}
```

Now I wonder how to avoid direct calls to initWithFrame method, like:

```
MyClass *theObj = [MyClass alloc]initWithFrame:theFrame];
```

I thought about throwing exception in initWithFrame definition:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    @throw ([NSException exceptionWithName:@"InitError" 
                                    reason:@"This class needs to be initialized with initWithFrame:aProperty: method" 
                                  userInfo:nil]);
}
```

Is this a good solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about calling your designated initializer with a default value for `aProperty` ?

Comment: Yep, and that won't break code that calls just `initWithFrame:` by not knowing what's a good default value for `aProperty`. And if you allow to change `aProperty` afterwards, it won't even be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Two techniques I use with initializers. I'm sure there a more.

Technique 1:

In initWithFrame call your initializer with a default value for a Property

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    return [self initWithFrame:frame aProperty:1.0f];
}
```

Technique 2:

Simply return nil;

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    return nil;
}
```